# how to access grammar components in antlr golang target

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

I am getting a compile error when accessing the operator value passed through the grammar rules. For example, I have the following grammar file:

```
grammar Expr;

@parser::header {
import (
    "os"
)
}

@parser::members {

func eval(left int, op antlr.Token, right int) int {
    if   (op.GetText() == "*") {
        return left * right
    } else if (op.GetText() == "+") {
        return left + right
    } else if (op.GetText() == "-") {
        return left - right
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
}

stat:   e NEWLINE
    |   NEWLINE                   
    ;

e returns [int v]
    : a=e op=('+'|'-') b=e  {
                $v = eval($a.v, $op, $b.v)
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "got args=%d %d\n", $a.v, $b.v)
                }
    | INT                   {
                $v = $INT.int
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "got number=%d\n", $v)
                }    
    ; 

MUL : '*' ;
DIV : '/' ;
ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

And this is the test code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "./parser"
    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)

func calc(inputfile string) {
        input, _ := antlr.NewFileStream(inputfile)// Setup the input
    lexer := parser.NewExprLexer(input)// Create the Lexer
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)
    p := parser.NewExprParser(stream)// Create the Parser
        p.Stat()
}

func main() {
    calc(os.Args[1])
}
```

These are the commands that I have run:

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Go -o parser -no-listener Expr.g4
go build expr_t.go
```

The above 2 programs work correctly. But I get a compile error (type mismatch) if I change the eval function's comparisons to something like this:

```
if   (op.tokenType == ExprParserMUL) {
    return left * right
```

How to get the op's value for comparison with ExprParseMUL?

Comment: Shouldn't `$a.v. $b.v` be with a comma instead: `$a.v, $b.v`?

Comment: Thanks, yes that was only a typo. Strange that go does not make these checks while compiling, eg I am printing 2 items but if there was a '.' then there was only 1 item to be printed. Anyway, that problem is solved now, so let me get back to the original problem again.

Comment: Oh, so the error you posted is still the same?

Comment: No, that problem is fixed. I just mentioned that the go compiler should have given a better error report, eg number of arguments mismatch in the print line, something like that. Anyway, I have another problem now, going to post it in a few minutes in the same question modified.

Comment: @BartKiers: now the lower grammar values are accessed, but I am not able to access the operator value, because I cant get its type properly.

Comment: Hi @R71, I'm learning antlr with Go, and found your example very valuable. However, I don't know how to output the final result. Would you post your finished code as another answer please? I'll upvote for you. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if (op.tokenType == ExprParserMUL) {
>     return left * right
> ```
>
> How to get the op's value for comparison with ExprParseMUL?

There isn't a `tokenType` field. Use `GetTokenType()`.

See: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Go/antlr/token.go

Comment: Thanks Bart, with this basic code running now I can start writing my grammars. I have another question on semantic predicates and using lookahead tokens with go, which I will post as a different question later.

Comment: Hi Bart, would you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230899/starting-antlr4-go-coding-with-the-lexer pls?