# Using antlr grammar rules to parse expression in Go

Tags: go, parsing, antlr4

Basically duplicating everything from [how to access grammar components in antlr golang target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842665/)

I have the following grammar file:

```
grammar Expr;

@parser::header {
import (
    "os"
)
}

@parser::members {

func eval(left int, op antlr.Token, right int) int {
    if   (op.GetText() == "*") {
        return left * right
    } else if (op.GetText() == "+") {
        return left + right
    } else if (op.GetText() == "-") {
        return left - right
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
}

stat:   e NEWLINE
    |   NEWLINE                   
    ;

e returns [int v]
    : a=e op=('+'|'-') b=e  {
                $v = eval($a.v, $op, $b.v)
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "got args=%d %d\n", $a.v, $b.v)
                }
    | INT                   {
                $v = $INT.int
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "got number=%d\n", $v)
                }    
    ; 

MUL : '*' ;
DIV : '/' ;
ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

And this is the test code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "./parser"
    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)

func calc(inputfile string) {
    input, _ := antlr.NewFileStream(inputfile)// Setup the input
    lexer := parser.NewExprLexer(input)// Create the Lexer
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)
    p := parser.NewExprParser(stream)// Create the Parser
        p.Stat()
}

func main() {
    calc(os.Args[1])
}
```

These are the commands that I have run:

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Go -o parser -no-listener Expr.g4
go build expr_t.go
```

The above 2 programs work correctly. However, how to print the final output? I tried with this and it is not working:

```
stat:   e NEWLINE {
    $v = $e.int
    fmt.Printf("=%d\n", $v)
                }
    |   NEWLINE                   
    ;
```

I went through the whole section of [The ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/), but wasn't able to find the details on the aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` rule returns a value called `v`:

```
e returns [int v]
 : ...
 | ...
 ;
```

So, instead of doing `$e.int` you should do `$e.v`:

```
stat
 : e NEWLINE { fmt.Printf("=%d\n", $e.v) }
 | NEWLINE                   
 ;
```

But, you could also let the entry rule `stat` return a value:

```
stat returns [int v]
 : a=e NEWLINE {$v = $a.v}
 | NEWLINE     {$v = 0}
 ;
```

and then in your code, do something like this:

```golang
func calc(inputfile string) {
    input, _ := antlr.NewFileStream(inputfile)
    lexer := parser.NewExprLexer(input)
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)
    p := parser.NewExprParser(stream)
    result := p.Stat()
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s", result.GetText())
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", result.GetV())
}
```

Code tested fine.

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot Bart, that's already good enough to get me to the correct path, and I succeeded after several tries. There are a few hurdles that I had to overcome, do you want me to edit your answer directly, or leave it and I comment in my OP instead?

Comment: @xpt given I know little of Go, feel free to edit my answer.